# Why the tmp still print 1 although there is no same synsets?

Tags: python, string, list, temp, synonym

I have two lists to compare:

```
word1 =  ['orange']
word2 =  ['woman']
```

And then I have this function to find a synsets for each word inside a list :

```
def getSynonyms(word):
synonymList1 = []
for data1 in word:
    wordnetSynset1 = wn.synsets(data1)
    tempList1=[]
    for synset1 in wordnetSynset1:
        synLemmas = synset1.lemma_names()
        for i in xrange(len(synLemmas)):
            word = synLemmas[i].replace('_',' ')
            #tempList1.append(pos_tag(word.split()))
            #if pos_tag(word.split()) not in tempList1:
                #tempList1.append(pos_tag(word.split()))
            if word not in tempList1:
                tempList1.append(word)
    synonymList1.append(tempList1)
return synonymList1

ds1 = getSynonyms([word1[0]])
ds2 = getSynonyms([word2[0]])
newds1 = ",".join(repr(e) for e in ds1)
newds2 = ",".join(repr(e) for e in ds2)

print newds1
print newds2
```

and this is the output :

```
[u'orange', u'orangeness', u'orange tree', u'Orange', u'Orange River', u'orangish']
[u'woman', u'adult female', u'charwoman', u'char', u'cleaning woman', u'cleaning lady', u'womanhood', u'fair sex']
```

and then I have another function. This function checks if there is similar synset between `word1` and `word2`. If a similar word is found, then the function will return 1 which means it is found. :

```
def cekSynonyms(word1, word2):
    tmp = 0
    ds1 = getSynonyms([word1[0]])
    ds2 = getSynonyms([word2[0]])
    newds1 = ",".join(repr(e) for e in ds1)
    newds2 = ",".join(repr(e) for e in ds2)

    for i in newds1:
        for j in newds2:
            if i == j:
                tmp = 1
            else:
                tmp = 0
    return tmp

print cekSynonyms(word1, word2)
```

But the output is `1`.

It looks like there is no similar synset between `word1` and `word2`. But why does it still results `1` not `0`?

Comment: `newds1` (lol) is a string. Iterating over it gives characters. If any character is shared it'll be 1

Answer (score 0):

Your loops always check the full lists and overwrites `tmp` in each iteration. So the last elements in the lists determine the returned value. Maybe you should stop the checking like

```
for i in newds1:
    for j in newds2:
        if i == j:
            tmp = 1
            print(i, j) #this will tell you why 1 is returned
            return tmp # <<<< return from function 
        else:
            tmp = 0
return tmp
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it still `1` although there is no similar synset

Comment: add a print(i, j) before the return statement to see what happens

Comment: which return statement and how about the indent?

Comment: I updated the code above. This should show why 1 is returned. Maybe the above from @anthony-sottile is correct and it iterates strings...

Comment: And were you able to fix it?